# Taking an input string and return a string list of only the words that start with "ba"?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a code in which would take a input string say:

```
I love bacon, but I love bananas more.
```

and return `["bacon","bananas"]` as output.

However I've ran into some troubles with my code, as I can't seem to properly implement this, currently my idea is that I would input a string and then use `word()` to split up the string into a string list, and then call getWrods to extract all the words with "ba" as their prefix and then return a list composed of words that start with "ba" for the main function allWords.

My code is as follows:

```
getWords:: String -> [String] -> [String]
getWords n [] = []
getWords n (x:xs)
 | n isPrefixOf x = [x] ++ getWords n xs
 |otherwise = getWords n xs


allWordss:: String -> [String]
allWordss n = getWords("ba" words(n))
```

Comment: Hint: `isPrefixOf` is just a function, so you can use it with `isPrefoxOf n x`, or ``n `isPrefixOf` x``.

Answer (score 2):

I think that by using [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=filter) here, you make the problem easier.

You can as filter condition use - like in your code [**`isPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf), but you here wrote in in "infix" notation, but without writing backticks. You thus can call the function with:

```
isPrefixOf n x
```

or:

```
n `isPrefixOf` x
```

A final problem with your code is that you write:

```
getWords("ba" words(n))
```

Here you seem to call a function with brackets, which is quite common in languages like Java, C++, etc. In Haskell however, a function `f` is called with a parameter `x` like `f x`, so you make a call with:

```
getWords "ba" (words n)
```

If we use `filter` here, we thus obtain:

```
allBaWords :: String -> [String]
allBaWords n = filter (\x -> isPrefixOf "ba" x) (words n)
```

or shorter:

```
allBaWords :: String -> [String]
allBaWords = filter (isPrefixOf "ba") . words
```

Answer (score 1):

We can break up the problem into three logical parts:

1. Separate a string into a list of words.
2. Recognize whether a word starts with "ba".
3. Given a list, get a list of all the elements that satisfy a certain condition (often called a *predicate*).

Let's start by importing a couple standard modules:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)
import Data.String (words)
```

Let's start with (2):

```
startsWithBa :: String -> Bool
startsWithBa s = -- something using isPrefixOf
```

As others have noted, you have to enclose `isPrefixOf` in backticks if you want to use it infix (which most people tend to do so it reads nicely).

Now to separate the string into words, we use

```
words :: String -> [String]
```

To extract just the strings that start with "ba", we can use the function

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

I'll let you try to put these pieces together.